# How customize delete confirmation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

**HTML:**

I don't want the confirmation box as will display in earlier model, I am trying to customize the confirmation popup box. See below is my code for that:

```
<div id="add_form" style="display:none">
    <h2> Are you sure want to delete the Follower</h2><br />
    <div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">    
        <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">

            Cancel
        </button>   
        <button type="submit" id="add" name="add" title="Add">
        Ok
             </button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: On a side note, you can just do `form.submit()` instead of `document.forms[id].submit()`

Comment: @roasted want to customize the delete confirmation popup box

Comment: @karthikr Since i have to set a confirmation box for form_id,have confusion how to apply in my application

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible, you can customize this using [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)